# Possible to remap `Esc` key to `Caps Lock` on a bluetooth keyboard

Tags: samsung, keyboard, terminal, external-keyboard

Samsung Galaxy Note 9 with any old bluetooth keyboard. How do I remap the `Esc` key to `Caps Lock`? And remap the `Caps Lock` key to `Esc`. Swap them basically.

I need this to make it easier to use Vim on Android. I prefer not to root.

Answer (score 2):

In Android 4.0 you could do this easy, you would need root permissions though. You most likely still can with root. Just checked can do easy with root. /System/usr/keylayout there are a couple files in there with keyboard layouts that you can edit with root permission. You can veiw but not edit in fx file manager, there are other files that control the same types of things in there.

Comment: Thanks for info. Prefer not to root though.

Answer (score 2):

It's totally possible without rooting.
Check out [ExKeyMo](https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/) (I'm the developer). It has an example with `Esc<->Caps` mapping.
If you need more than one layout take a look at [custom-keyboard-layout](https://github.com/ris58h/custom-keyboard-layout) (I'm the developer).

UPDATE:

ExKeyMo web app is not available on Heroku anymore. You'll have to run it locally. See the project's page on [GitHub](https://github.com/ris58h/exkeymo-web).

Comment: I tried this scheme with ExKeyMo, and downloaded and installed the app, and enabled the custom layout, but it didn't do anything; what am I doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/pX01KMcX (I'm on Android 10.)

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx Unfortunately Android doesn't notify about errors in KCM files. Could you try examples from ExKeyMo (`Caps-Lock as Esc` and other)? Do they work for you? If so, you could then start with your mappings (one-by-one) to find the issue.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx you can check your KCM file using [validatekeymaps](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/input/validate-keymaps) tool. There is [web version](https://ris58h.github.io/validatekeymaps/).

Comment: It worked! Go to the docs to learn how to set it up: https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/docs.html